# Decryption not decrypting the data although no errors

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I am new to encryption concept. Am trying to use AES encryption to encrypt a file which seems to be working fine. But when I use the decryption, I get no errors but the data is not decrypted. The decryption code is below

```
public static string DecryptData(string sFileInPath, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    String data = null;

    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(sFileInPath);

    if (!File.Exists(sFileInPath))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("FilenotExists");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    try
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;
            aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }

            data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());

            msDecrypt.Close();
        }

        return data;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string status = string.Format("{0}: {1}", statustype.Failed.ToString(), ex.ToString());
        return status;
    }
}
```

Call to the decrypt method is

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider oAes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
string xml = Utility.DecryptData_AES(sfile,oAes.Key,oAes.IV);
```

Encryption method:

```
   public static byte[] EncryptData(AlertEnvelope alertenvelope, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {

        if (alertenvelope == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("alertenvelope");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;

        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesAlg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;


            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);


            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(alertenvelope);
                    }

                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
             }
            }
        }


        return encrypted;

    }
```

I will appreciate if someone can help me understand why the data is not being decrypted

Comment: What is your encypt method and why are you using padding PaddingMode.None?

Comment: I was getting an error  "invalid padding and padding cannot be removed". The encryption method is :

Comment: How did you encrypt message? If only one of values that was  used for encryption (key,IV,mode,padding, cyper (number of bits)) does not match, you will get error.

Comment: Since the calls to both the encrypt and decrypt methods are independent, how do I make sure the same values are passed for key and IV?

Comment: This has to be (pre)defined on both sides for this to work. It is called  protocol and keys. I can't imagine work it any other way.

Comment: Can you please point me to some working code for this kind of implementation?

Comment: doest example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx work in your case?

Comment: Not really - the methods are almost the same as I have mine. But the call to encrypt and decrypt are not in the same method for me. I am encrypting the file when its being written. While later another service is trying to grab that file and decrypt it.

Comment: As for the key that should be pre-established before encryption/decryption. The IV can be prefixed to the ciphertext, it doesn't need to be confidential although it does need to be *unpredictable* for CBC mode (if you reuse the key anyway).